# UPS Quantum View API Error Code: 330052

Tags: ups

I am new to using UPS APIs. I have been looking for a way to pull tracking information for packages under our account. I believe the Quantum View API by UPS provides that functionality.

My issue comes with deciphering the error that I have been getting. I know my credential are set up to be administration level and I have the correct UPS  Access License Number.

The error I get is: **330052**

The accompanying message is: **The user has been blocked from downloading subscription files because of the following inactive status(es): CompanyQVD, UserQVD.**

The documentation for this API says nothing else about this message.

Does anyone have any experience in this and can point my in the right direction to get this solved?

Thanks,

Lewis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are getting the same error that I was getting above, that is due to Quantum View Data being disabled on your UPS profile.

You can double check this by going to [ups.com](http://ups.com), tracking tab -> Quantum View Data. You'll need to login to your ups account as well.

If disabled, you need to contact your account rep to activate this portion.

Quantum View Manage and Quantum View Notify are 2 separate services and the Quantum View API runs off of Quantum View Notify.

They should really change the naming schemes for these...

Hope this helps,

-Lewis

Comment: The Quantum View Notify Options are available in the Shipping API (mostly).If anyone is searching for notifications and stuff, thats all located in the Shipping API.

Comment: @Florian For the Quantum View api to work, do you need to enable the Quantum View while shipping the package (shipping api)? In /QVEvents endpoint, I keep receiving `Failure: There are no files for the given Request`